# POS Printer with Quasar and Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, quasar

I'm pretty new to Quasar, but I really love it. I have been looking for ways to print on a POS Printer for several days but I can't find any solution using Capacitor. Can you give me any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

exist Prints documents or HTML rendered content

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/printer

npm install cordova-plugin-printer

npm install @ionic-native/printer

ionic cap sync